# BizTalk dynamic solicit-response send port - Set Timeout

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, send-port

I would like to increase the timeout for a dynamic solicit-response send port I have created on BizTalk 2013.

Currently the timeout is set to 1 minute, which is default by BizTalk, but every time a large message comes through, BizTalk is generating a timeout error, because the message is taking more than 1 minute to process.

One way to solve it was to make the orchestration atomic, therefore having control of the timeout period as to when an instance can be terminated, but this does not come in handy, since my Orchestration is not transactional.

This leaves me with the possibility of setting the timeout period through the BizTalk Configuration manager. However, since I need to use a dynamic solicit-response send port, I cannot find a way to set the timeout.

How can you set the timeout on a dynamic solicit-response send port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `WCF.BindingConfiguration` property on your port.  For example, if you want to set the open timeout:

```
Port_Name(WCF.BindingConfiguration)=@”<binding name=””WCF-Custom”” openTimeout=””00:10:00″” />”;
```

Comment: I used a slightly different approach to the code in the orchestration but in the end, yes, I had to do this through the code in the Message Assignment shape.

Comment: Can you post an answer with your different approach?  It may be of some interest to others ;-)